# How can I take integer regex?

Tags: python, regex, integer

I'm trying to use regex in Python for taking some parts of a text. From a text I need to take this kind of substring '2016-049172'. So what's the equivalent regex?
Thank you very much.

Here's a piece of code:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\s-\s[0-9]+[0-9]$]")
my_string = 'Ticketing TSX - 2016-049172'

matches = re.findall(pattern,my_string)
print matches
```

Of course, my output is empty list. 
(I apologize for initial bad post, I'm new)

Comment: Please add 1) Example input; 2) Desired output; 3) what you have tried.

Comment: *Are* you trying to use regex? Where's your try? Have you read any of the various tutorials on regex syntax? Is it always going to be four digits, a dash then six more digits?

Comment: Check out http://www.regex101.com it can help you work through regex once you have learned more about it.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @busfault Thank you, I'll give a look.

Comment: Why did you think that regex *would* work? It's: whitespace, dash, whitespace, multiple digits, a single digit, the end of the string, close square bracket. It makes no sense. Don't you just want `\d{4}-\d{6}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have posted, the regular expression you are looking for is:

```
\d{4}-\d{6}
```

The full code I would use:

```
import re

my_string = 'Ticketing TSX - 2016-049172'
matches = re.findall(r"\d{4}-\d{6}", my_string)

print matches
```

If, for example, the length of the second digit varies from 6 to 8 digits, you will need to update your regular expression to this.

```
\d{4}-\d{6,8}
```

All of the details about regex and using regex in Python is available in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1):

The regex to use is this:

```
\d{4}-\d{6}
```

Updating your example code, this will do it for you:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\d{4}-\d{6}")
my_string = 'Ticketing TSX - 2016-049172'

matches = re.findall(pattern,my_string)
print matches
```